# How I can identify holes in a 3D CAD file?

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition

How I can identify holes in a 3D CAD file?  I want to identify different types of holes, counterbored or countersunk holes. My program lets me extract, for example, the faces and adjacency of the faces.
I am talking about the Siemens NX for example. 
The different types of holes you can see there:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D_VwwfDrdggc&psig=AOvVaw1kIYdOt2qxazSYFXwHuXpb&ust=1586329824363000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCOjd1qHh1egCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Maybe you could provide a picture of the specific holes that you want to identify. Also, what program are you talking about?